# Why are some Android Studio classes highlighted with different colors?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I did notice some classes are highlighted in blue in my project structure. What is the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To expand on [tyczj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949983/469080), if version control is being used on the project then file names may be highlighted in different colours in the file explorer, editor tabs and active changes tab:

- **White** - No changes to the file since the last commit
- **Blue** - File exists in version control and has been modified since the last commit
- **Green** - File does not exist in version control and **has** been staged for the next commit
- **Red** - File does not exist in version control and **has not** been staged for the next commit
- **Yellow** - File has been moved from its previous location in version control, but its contents have not been modified
- **Grey** (only in Active Changes tab) - File has been deleted locally but not in version control

So in your example you have two modified files that already exist in version control.

---

As [Zoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe) points out, this reflects the default colour scheme in Android Studio and IntelliJ. These colours may be modified via `Settings -> Editor -> Color scheme -> VCS`

Comment: Just feel like pointing out this is the standard setting; different themes, plugins, or settings, can alter these to have different colors. `Settings->Editor->Color scheme->VCS`

Answer (score 6):

Because you are using version control and you have uncommitted changes for those files

Answer (score 3):

Highlighted color is for Version Control.

If you create new file and do not commit it to GIT it's Highlighted with **RED** color

If you change in a file that already committed, it's highlighted with **BLUE** color.

[image]