# What does green and red colour indicates in Android Studio Can anyone have solution?

Tags: java, android

In the drawable, layout, mipmap, values, why i'm getting such green and red combination colour what they indicates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950145.

Answer (score 0):

If the project uses VCS(for example, git), then the files that are under version control are marked in green, and those that are not under control are marked in red.